# Add to Html.dropdownlist an extra option.text and option.value mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a dropdownlist as follows:

```
@Html.DropDownList("accounts", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Accounts"], "--- All ---")
```

when I want to retrieve the value (of the extra option) of the dropdown from javascript I get an empty string, how can I set the value of ddl, my script looks likes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#accounts").change(function () {
        var idaccount = $("#accounts > option:selected").attr("value");
        $("#ordersTabel>tbody>tr").each(function (index, itemData) {
            $this = $(this)
            var accountintable = $("#accountKolom", itemData).text();
            if (idaccount == "--- All ---") {
                $this.show();
            }

            if (idaccount != $.trim(accountintable)) {
                $this.hide();
            }

        });
    });
});
```

Thanks,

Hicham.

Comment: the value of the optionlabel is supposed to be an empty string...

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned in the comments, the default option value is supposed to be an empty string so that the Required attribute works as expected: it validates for the presence of a value.

However, if you are asking "How do I insert additional options with values into an existing IEnumerable" you can use the [Enumerable.Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) extension method:

```
var accountOptions = <do whatever you do to generate your existing collection>;
var allOptions = new[]{new SelectListItem{
    Value = <your value>, 
    Text = "--- All ---";}}.Concat(accountOptions);
ViewData["Accounts"] = allOptions;
```